# Firebase compound queries always get empty results

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a query in my nodesjs server (functions section) in firebase

I created a collection with 3 documents and 2 fields each - email and timestamp

when I do a query for email -> I get the right documents

```
await admin.firestore().collection('sessions').where('email', '==', 'email@gmail.com').get()
```

when I do a query for timestamp -> I get the right documents

```
await admin.firestore().collection('sessions').where('timestamp', '>', 1601164800).get()
```

but...
when I do a query for both email and timestamp -> I get no documents...

```
await admin.firestore().collection('sessions').where('email', '==', email).where('timestamp', '>', 1601164800).get()
```

the way I understand it is when I do multiple 'where' it's like a logical AND so if I get the same records in the first query and the seconds query I should get them in the third query as well

I also read that I need to create an index in case I want to do multiple where that have an equal operator and range operator so I created one and no luck :(
all the data I created manually - both the collection + documents and the index

is there something that I miss?

[collection data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGgOl.png)
[indexes definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8VKF.png)

this is the code of full process of getting the docs
the result array I return to the client and I get an empty array

```
   async function getInfo() {
       let query = admin.firestore().collection('sessions').where('email', '==', 'email@gmail.com').where('timestamp', '>', 1601164800);

       let dbData = await query.get();
       let result = [];

       dbData.forEach(doc => {
           let data = doc.data();
           // this log is to see how many docs I get
           logger.log(data); 
           result.push(data);
       });

       return result;
   }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show in more detail how you created the documents, and explain the expected results of the query.  If you created the documents manually, show a screenshot.  We need to be able to see that your timestamp field matches what you use in the query.  In general, there should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the behavior.  If there is an error, please share the error message.

Comment: (1) Did you generate the composite index automatically (using the auto-generated link) or manually? (2) Did you receive a missing composite index error before and not after creating the index? (3) Are you certain that a document exists where both fields are true?

Comment: @bsod I generated the index using the firebase dashboard and didn't get any error, it just took a few minutes to build. yeah I'm sure it should return something cause when searching apart it gives me the same docs and just when doing it together it gives me empty results...

Comment: @DougStevenson you're right, I added a screenshot of the info (all the docs are the same so showing one of them is enough) and I don't get any errors - just an empty result

Comment: Please show the full code that you're using to process the results, and show how you know there are no matching documents.  Also hard code **everything**, including email and collection name.

Comment: @DougStevenson added the code of my func with hard coded info, and I know there are no matching docs cause I return the results to the client and get an empty array

Comment: I'm seeing the same error, with a string id field and a timestamp. If I query a single field, it works, but when I mix both the result is empty.

Thanks for opening this question.

Answer (score 0):

What about iterating over `dbData.docs`?

```js
logger.log(`Documents retrieved: ${dbData.size}`)

return dbData.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
```

- https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html

Comment: oh thanks, I actually prefer the .map way - I just didn't know how to do it

Comment: indeed, this functions should return something as I have tested it. I think the issue is either in the logger not "logging" or how are you invoking this function. Can you please the normal `console.log()` and try again. Also, posting a code snippet of how are you invoking the function would be helpful

Comment: I don't think it matters - this function is just a test function where I try to get the info, when I set only one 'where' it works fine and when I set 2 'where' it returns nothing. As for the log thing, again it doesn't matter what I put there cause there is nothing I can show you, it doesn't get there as the result is empty